# Preg Match circumflex with ^ in php

Tags: php, mysql, function, preg-match-all

I know I am going to get a lot of asinine comments, but I cannot figure this out no matter what I do. I have a function here

```
$filter = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `filter`");
    $fil = mysql_fetch_array($filter);
    $bad = $fil['filter'];

$bword = explode(",", $bad);
    function wordfilter($output,$bword){
    $badWords = $bword;
$matchFound = preg_match_all("/(" . implode($badWords,"|") . ")/i",$output,$matches);

if ($matchFound) {
  $words = array_unique($matches[0]);
  foreach($words as $word) {
    $output = preg_replace("/$word/","*****",$output);
  }
}
return $output;
    }
```

I know bad word filters are frowned upon, but my client has requested this.

Now i have a list in the database here are a few entries.

```
^ass$,^asses$,^asshopper,^cock$,^coon,^cracker$,^cum$,^dick$,^fap$,^heeb$,^hell$,^homo$,^humping,^jap$,^mick$,^muff$,^paki$,^phap$,^poon$,^spic$,^tard$,^tit$,^tits$,^twat$,^vag$,ass-hat,ass-pirate,assbag
```

as you can see I am using a circumflex and dollar signs for certain words.

The problem I am having is with the first three words beginning with `ass` it is blocking out the word even if i write something like `glasses` or `grasshoppers` but everything past the first 3 work fine, I have tried adding 3 entries before these in-case that was the problem, but unfortunately it isn't.

Is there something wrong with how i have this written?

Comment: You should look at open-source solutions for this instead of inventing your own mechanism.

Comment: @SalmanA I have tried a lot of open source scripts for this but none of them do exactly what I need them to

Comment: Try changing your Regex to `'/\b('.implode("|",$badwords).')\b/i'` and remove `^` and `$` in your database.

Comment: @Passerby that doesn't work either, it just starts messing up other words i have in the database, there are about 150+ words in it.

Comment: @kira423 Then I'm interested in how your `$output` look like. `^` and `$` means "start of string/line" and "end of string/line". That's why you shouldn't add them to your database directly - you're probably expecting `"bad ass boy"` to be filtered, and `^ass$` wouldn't do it, but `\bass\b` should do.

Comment: @Passerby I changed it to `$matchFound = preg_match_all("/\b(" . implode("|",$badWords) . ")\b/i",$output,$matches);` as you said but i when i took those out it messed it up, putting them back in makes it work fine... if you post your comment as an answer i can make it as the correct answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from comment:

Try to use `\b` to detect words:

```
$matchFound = preg_match_all('/\b('.implode($badWords,"|").')\b/i',$output,$matches);
```